# Resize images in batch

Tags: images

I want to resize images on server, I have more than 7000 images in library of my WordPress site. I want to resize all images on server itself. I know that regenerate thumbnails plugin can be used, but for that I will have to keep my browser window open all the day and it can even crash somewhere in middle that will lead me to resize all images again.

Does anyone have better idea to do this stuff? Please explain answer in brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ankit
you can re-size images by using this script via terminal:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);

require_once('./wp-load.php');
require_once( './wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

for($i=0;$i<=500;$i++){

$attachments =& get_children(array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'numberposts' => 50,
        'paged' => $i,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => null
    ), ARRAY_A);

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $image = get_post($attachment['ID']);
    $original_size_path = get_attached_file($image->ID);

    if (false === $original_size_path || !file_exists($original_size_path)) {
        echo 'File Not Found: ';
    } else {
        $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($image->ID, $original_size_path);

        if (is_wp_error($metadata) || empty($metadata))
            echo 'Unknown failure reason: '. $original_size_path;

        wp_update_attachment_metadata($image->ID, $metadata);
    }
}

echo 'Done page '. $i.' ====== ';
mail('youremailid+1@domain.com',('Page'.$i.'done'),('Page'.$i.'done'));
unset($attachments);
unset($image);
unset($original_size_path);
unset($metadata);
sleep(1);
}
mail('youremailid+1@domain.com;','Done','Done Images Thumbnail Generation');
?>
```

You just need to change the value of $i in for loop  and your email address.Save this file as "something.php" and run this in your terminal via ssh.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk Resize Media automatically resizes huge image uploads and makes sure the maximum upload size is respected for all uploaded images.
Try this plugin : [Bulk Resize Media](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-resize-media/)

Comment: Will this handle 7K images on one go ?

Comment: I have tried 3k images. it work's fine.

Comment: What about your server space ? are you using shared hosting?

Comment: I have dedicated hosting.